# Blazor - one component should react to a method of another component

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor

I'm using this https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.I18nText to quickly translate text in my HTML and it works fine as long as I write a tag like `<p>@MyText.Example</p>`. But if I try to do the same with `Lists` (seen in my `FooterLayout.razor`) it is a bit different. The list has to change in the `FooterLayout` when I change a value in my `NaviHeaderBar`.

My **MainLayout.razor** looks like this:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="grid-c-1 grid-r-1">
        <NaviHeaderBar />
    </div>

    <div class="grid-c-1 grid-r-1">
        <LoginDisplay />
    </div>


    <div class="grid-c-1 grid-r-1">
        @Body
    </div>

    <div class="grid-c-1 grid-r-1">
        <FooterLayout />
    </div>
</div>
```

In my **NaviHeaderBar.razor** I have this  tag:

```
                <select id="selectMenuItem" style="background-color: transparent; font-size: 16px; border: none; font-weight: bolder; color: grey;" 
@onchange="OnChangeCurrentLang">
                    <option value="en" selected="@(CurrentLang == "en")">English</option>
                    <option value="de" selected="@(CurrentLang == "de")">Deutsch</option>
                </select>
```

with this code

```
@code
{
    private string CurrentLang;
    I18nText.NaviHeaderBarLanguage MyText = new I18nText.NaviHeaderBarLanguage();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        MyText = await I18nText.GetTextTableAsync<I18nText.NaviHeaderBarLanguage>(this);
    }

    private async Task OnChangeCurrentLang(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        CurrentLang = args.Value as string;
        await I18nText.SetCurrentLanguageAsync(CurrentLang);
    }
}
```

My **FooterLayout.razor** looks like this:

```
                @foreach (LinkInput link in linkListInput)
                {
                    <a href=@link.linkURl style="height: 30px; line-height: 20px;">
                        <li class="list-item">@link.text</li>
                    </a>
                }

            </ul>
        </div>
```

with this code:

```
@code{
    public List<LinkInput> linkListInput = new List<LinkInput>(){
        new LinkInput("text1", "/url1/"),
        new LinkInput("text2", "/url1/"),
        new LinkInput("text3", "/url1/"),
        new LinkInput("text4", "/url1/"),
        new LinkInput("text5", "/url1/")
    };

I18nText.FooterLayoutLanguage MyText = new I18nText.FooterLayoutLanguage();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    MyText = await I18nText.GetTextTableAsync<I18nText.FooterLayoutLanguage>(this);

}
}
```

I want to change the `new LinkInput("text1", "/url1/"),` to `new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1/"),` but this won't work. My Error Message: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'FooterLayout.MyText'`.

To fix this error I did this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    MyText = await I18nText.GetTextTableAsync<I18nText.FooterLayoutLanguage>(this);

    linkListInput.Clear();
    linkListInput.Add(new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1"));
    linkListInput.Add(new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1"));
    linkListInput.Add(new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1"));
    linkListInput.Add(new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1"));
    linkListInput.Add(new LinkInput(MyText.Example, "/url1"));
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Now when I change the language setting my `FooterLayout.razor` does not change it's text. I could make it change it's text with for example `@onmouseover`. But this would mean that I have to hover over my `FooterLayout`.

Is there a way to change it's text right when I change the language setting in `NaviHeaderBar`? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of state management (like Fluxor) or you need some kind of messaging system.

```
public class MessagingSystem
{
  public event EventHandler<EventArgs> LanguageChanged;

  public void NotifyLanguageChanged()
  {
    LanguageChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

You can then inject that into your header and call `NotifyLanguageChanged` when you select a new language.

In your footer you can inject it and then subscribe to `LanguageChanged`, and in that event call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`.

Remember though, if you consume a standard .NET event then you must implement `IDisposable` on your component so you can also unsubscribe, otherwise the service will hold a reference to your component forever and it won't be garbage collected.

Personally, I'd just use Fluxor :)